# Generic KeyedCollection of derived class

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

I've looked around and haven't found anything quite matching my problem, though [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13280108/collection-of-derived-classes-that-have-generic-base-class) is certainly close. Basically, I have a KeyedCollection of Page objects as a base, and I want strongly typed collections of derived objects to come from it. Specifically, I have:

`public class Page
public class Category : Page
public class PageList<T> : KeyedCollection<string, T> where T : Page
public class CategoryList : PageList<Category>`

Now, this seems fine up until I want to call a method from within the `PageList<T>` using something like `DoSomethingTo(this)` which is currently declared as `DoSomethingTo(PageList<Page> pageList)`. This gives me a casting error.

What I'd like to be able to do, as you've probably already figured out is to use `DoSomething(this)` from within either the `PageList<T>` class *or* within the CategoryList class.

How do I make this work...or do I? I tried similar methods to what was suggested in the question I linked above, but I couldn't get anything to work. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what you're doing now and exactly what error message you get?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `PageList<Page>` and `PageList<Category>` are not covariant. The are effectively completely unrelated types. Even though T is a derived type, the resulting generic collections are not.

If you think about it, this is correct, because otherwise there would be nothing stopping you from passing a `CatagoryList` to a function that expects a `PageList` which could then add a `Page` to the catagory collection which would be invalid.

To help with situations like this, C# 4 added support for covariant interfaces. These allow limited covariance by using in and out keywords to restrict what you can do.

Your linked question uses this, which you could do also.

```
interface IPageList<out T> where T : Page
{
}

public class PageList<T> : KeyedCollection<string, T>, IPageList<T> where T : Page
{
}


DoSomethingTo(IPageList<Page> pageList)
{   
}
```

Comment: I tried something like this, but maybe I just didn't get it right somewhere along the way. I'll poke at it again tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I remember the problem now. The problem with doing this is that IPageList<Page> is no longer a KeyedCollection, so DoSomethingTo can't iterate through it.

Comment: Oh, and just as importantly, I need it to be indexable as well.

I'm guessing I'm asking the impossible?